# How to get the childs of selected parent only from xml using jquery?

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-mobile

I'm learning jquery and i'm trying to get the load data from xml using jquery.I'm getting the parent tags in the listview and when i'm clicking on the particular parent its getting all the child tags of all the parents.

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<page count="56" name="ebook">
  <sections>
    <section count="7" name="Seduce Your Partner" order="1">
      <content file="93828.txt" order="1">Balmy with rich perfumes</content>
      <content file="93829.txt" order="2">Wear a fine dress</content>
      <content file="93830.txt" order="3">Welcome to Love Abode</content>
      <content file="93831.txt" order="4">Rekindle your love</content>
      <content file="93832.txt" order="5">Flower a love messanger</content>
      <content file="93833.txt" order="6">Perfumes and Aromas</content>
      <content file="93834.txt" order="7">Gain a women&amp;apos;s heart</content>
    </section>
    <section count="6" name="The Touch of Love" order="2">
      <content file="93835.txt" order="8">A Love Message</content>
      <content file="93836.txt" order="9">An awakening kiss</content>
      <content file="93837.txt" order="10">Heading South with Confidence</content>
      <content file="93838.txt" order="11">Caressing</content>
      <content file="93839.txt" order="12">Stroking</content>
      <content file="93840.txt" order="13">Blows &amp;amp; Cries</content>
    </section>
    <section count="8" name="Beyond Touch" order="3">
      <content file="93841.txt" order="14">Watch, Listen &amp;amp; Experiment</content>
      <content file="93842.txt" order="15">Blindfolded</content>
      <content file="93843.txt" order="16">Embrace of Jaghana</content>
      <content file="93844.txt" order="17">Piercing Embrace</content>
      <content file="93845.txt" order="18">Twining of a Creeper</content>
      <content file="93846.txt" order="19">Line of Jewels</content>
      <content file="93847.txt" order="20">Token of Remembrance</content>
      <content file="93848.txt" order="21">Oils and Lotions</content>
    </section>
  </sections>
</page>
```

This is my xml file.I'm getting all the parent tags with attribute "name" but the problem is when i'm click on the particular parent tag in the list its getting all the child tags of all the parent.

see the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/bhvxV/

can anyone help me to find the solution for getting the child of that parent only.

Thanks in Advance.

Thanks Omar..this is what i'm looking but i want to know one more thing "how to open the file in the child tag".for example in the above xml file" we have a child tag like below this for every parent.

```
<content file="93828.txt" order="1">Balmy with rich perfumes</content>
      <content file="93829.txt" order="2">Wear a fine dress</content>
```

when i'm click on the child tag example:Balmy with rich perfumes  "93828.txt" file has to open.How to open this files when i click on the childrens.

For example "93828.txt" file: for "Balmy with rich perfumes" in "seduce your partner"

```
<html><head><title></title></head><body>
<div id="mobi_content"><h1>Balmy with rich perfumes</h1><div id="dataSectionInstanceId-182047" class="mobifusion_data"><p><I>The outer room, balmy with rich perfumes, should contain a bed, soft, agreeable to the sight; covered with a clean white cloth... having garlands and bunches of flowers upon it. </I><P>A well-appointed bedroom will inspire many nights (and mornings) of pleasure. Ideally, your bed should be comfortable and inviting, with enough space around it to make you feel at ease. You should be able to move energetically without producing annoying squeaks or thumps. Whether your taste runs to red velvet or white linen, strive to establish an aesthetic of pleasure, relaxation, and entertainment. Items you may want within easy reach include:<P>*Drinking water and tissues<P>*Mints or candied aniseed<P>*Lubricant and condoms<P>*Neck pillow (for under your hips)<P>*Love toys and ostrich feather<P>*Scented lotions and massage oil<P>*Incense, candles, and matches<P>Make sure your bedroom smells delicious and is softly lit, and don't forget suitable music. Consider placing a candle where it will cast your lovemaking shadows on the wall, or a mirror where you can catch a glimpse of yourselves. Add a bowl of delicious fruits, books of love poetry, even board games.<P><img src="multimedia/frontimage1.png" id="mobi_image_1694" class="inline-img"/></p></div></div></body></html>
```

93835.txt: for "A Love Message" in The Touch Of Love"

```
<html><head><title></title></head><body>
<div id="mobi_content"><h1>A Love Message</h1><div id="dataSectionInstanceId-182061" class="mobifusion_data"><p><I>When a girl touches her lover's lip with her tongue, and having shut her eyes, places her hands on those of her lover, it is called the</I><b> touching kiss.</b><P>Each day offers an opportunity to receive or deliver the <b>Touching Kiss,</b> the most tender and electrifying of the genre. You can proceed from there to the three basic kisses, <b>Straight</b>, <b>Bent</b>, and <b>Turned</b>.<P><b>Straight</b> is just as it sounds, with the two of you facing each other. <b>Bent</b> is done with heads tipped to the side, and <b>Turned</b> is done when one person takes the other's chin and head in hand and turns his or her face up for a kiss. If you engage in any of these kisses with urgency, it's called the <b>Pressed Kiss</b>.<P>An intense crush can drive a lover to distraction, leading to a kiss of the beloved's reflection in a mirror or water, or shadow on a wall. When that's done it's called a <b>Kiss Showing the Intention</b>, and only those dizzy with love do it. If they give a peck to a child, picture, or figurine in the presence of their sweetheart, making it obvious for whom the kiss was truly intended, it's called a <b>Transferred Kiss.</b> This is a sneaky way to send a love message in mixed company. At a movie or a party, you can show your love discreetly by kissing your fingertips and touching them to your darling's finger or toes.<P><img src="multimedia/frontimage2.png" id="mobi_image_1695" class="inline-img"/></p></div></div></body></html>
```

see this link with updated Html file and Js: http://jsfiddle.net/Hs38x/3/

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Thank u very much Omar..its working very fine..i tried and update the code for dynamically changing the header its working fine but it has a problem like its changing the header after entering in the page.. check this one : http://jsfiddle.net/SP6ww/2/

Comment: For the header, `$('[data-role=header] h1').text('new text')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find `content` based on `section` **id**. Check the example and the code below.

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/bhvxV/5/)**

Create list of `section`:

```
var xml = 'xml code here';

$(xml).find('section').each(function () {
 var section = $(this).attr("name");
 var order = $(this).attr("order");
 $("#section_list").append('<li><a href="#chapter" id="' + order + '">' + section + '  </a> </li>');
 $("#section_list").listview('refresh');
});
```

Based on clicked list item, fetch it's `id` and pull contents based on the `id`:

```
$("#section_list").on('click', 'a', function () {
 var order = $(this).attr('id'); // clicked item id/order
 $("#content_list").empty(); // wipe it before you add items
 $(xml).find('section[order="' + order + '"] content').each(function () {
  var content = $(this).text();
  var file = $(this).attr('file'); // added this and file="" inside <a> link below
  $("#content_list").append('<li><a href="#" file="' + file + '" id="">' + content + ' </a> </li> ');
 });
 $("#content_list").listview('refresh');
});
```

---

### Updated answer

Reference to your comment and updated question, here is the code. But first, you need to add `file.txt` to the `<a>` link as follows.

```
var file = $(this).attr('file');
$('#content_list').append('<li><a href="#" file="' + file + '">' + content + ' </a></li>');
```

Once you have the links updated with `file.txt` names, the below code will `.load()` contents of `file.txt` into a new page.

```
$(document).on('click', '#content_list li a', function () {
 var file = $(this).attr('file');
 if($('[data-role=page]#words').length === 0) {
  $($.mobile.pageContainer).append('<div data-role="page" id="words" data-add-back-btn="true"><div data-role="header"><h1>Words</h1></div><div data-role="content"></div></div>');
  $('[data-role=page]#words [data-role=content]').load('path/'+file);
  $.mobile.changePage('#words');
 }
 else {
  $('[data-role=page]#words [data-role=content]').empty();
  $('[data-role=page]#words [data-role=content]').load('path/'+file);
  $.mobile.changePage('#words');
 }
});
```

I have given the page an id `#words` change it to whatever suits you.

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Thanks Omar..this is what i'm looking and i want to know about how to open a file in the child tag. can you see the above one i updated my data.Thanks in Advance